# How to vectorize a numpy for loop that has a multiple indexed access

Tags: python, numpy

`unigram` is an array shape `(N, M, 100)`

I would like to remove the `for` loop and perform all the calculations.

`seq` is a 1D array of size `M`, and the size of `M` maybe up to 10000.

I would like to remove the for loop and vectorize it for easier computation.

```py
batch_size, seq_len, num_labels = unigram_scores.shape
broadcast = np.broadcast_to(seq, (batch_size, seq_len))


for i in range(0, broadcast.shape[1]):
    n_seq[i] = unigram_scores[np.arange(batch_size), i , broadcast[:,i]]
```

edit:
answer by @hpaulj worked perfectly and also has the advantage of not having to install any extra dependency 
the speed up was much lower than I expected

I ended up finally installing numba

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def calculate_unigram_probability(unigram_scores,seq):
    
    batch_size, seq_len, num_labels = unigram_scores.shape
    broadcast = np.broadcast_to(seq, (batch_size, seq_len))

    for i in prange( broadcast.shape[1]):
       n_seq[i] = unigram_scores[np.arange(batch_size), i , broadcast[:,i]]


    return n_seq
```

which is also taking a a bit too long, Currently I am trying to move it from the cpu to cuda which should bring about the speedup I am hoping for

Comment: What's the `seq.dtype`?  What's the shape/dtype of `unigram_scores[np.arange(batch_size), i , broadcast[:,i]]`?   Looks like it's `(batch_size,)`.

Comment: What operations are you using here? Can you be more specific? Can you add an example input and expected output? Chances are this is something in numpy's wheelhouse but it's not super clear what you're trying to do. There are a lot of objects in your provided code which aren't defined or described so we can really only guess (`unigram_scores`, `n_seq`, `seq`)...

Comment: @hpaulj seq.dtype is float32  shape of ```unigram_scores[np.arange(batch_size), i , broadcast[:,i]]``` is m\ broadcast[:,i] a single number

Comment: @ddejohn ```unigram_scores``` is an numpy array of shape (N M 100) , seq is a 1 dimensional array of size M. unigram_score is 3d array of probabilities of unigrams and seq is a sequence of unigrams , while n_seq is a sequence of probabilities of the appearance of the unigrams

Comment: Actually it was `n_seq` that I should have asked about.  I also disagree about the `unigram[....]` being a single number. In my tests it is (N,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [129]: N,M = 5,3
In [130]: unigram=np.arange(N*M*4).reshape(N,M,4)
In [131]: seq = np.arange(M)
In [132]: b_seq = np.broadcast_to(seq, (N,M))
```

For a single `i`:

```
In [133]: i=0; unigram[np.arange(N),i,b_seq[:,i]]
Out[133]: array([ 0, 12, 24, 36, 48])
```

For all `i` in the range:

```
In [136]: i=np.arange(M)[:,None]
In [137]: unigram[np.arange(N),i,b_seq[:,i]]
Out[137]: 
array([[[ 0, 12, 24, 36, 48],
        [ 5, 17, 29, 41, 53],
        [10, 22, 34, 46, 58]],

        ...
       [[ 0, 12, 24, 36, 48],
        [ 5, 17, 29, 41, 53],
        [10, 22, 34, 46, 58]]])
```

A (5,3,5) array.   This (5,3) might be better)

```
In [141]: i=np.arange(M); unigram[np.arange(N)[:,None],i,b_seq[:,i]]
Out[141]: 
array([[ 0,  5, 10],
       [12, 17, 22],
       [24, 29, 34],
       [36, 41, 46],
       [48, 53, 58]])
```

We don't need to index `b_seq`: `unigram[np.arange(N)[:,None],i,b_seq]`

Or even use; let the indexing `broadcast` `seq`:

```
unigram[np.arange(N)[:,None],i,seq]
```

and with the help of `ix_`:

```
In [145]: I,J=np.ix_(np.arange(N), np.arange(M))
In [146]: unigram[I,J,seq]
```

To get a visual idea of what this indexing does, look at `unigram`.  It's pull 'diagonals' from successive blocks/batches:

```
In [147]: unigram
Out[147]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]],
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use x.flatten() to reshape a 3d array to 1d array (x must be a numpy array )

in your case :

```
broadcast = broadcast.flatten()
```

this will transform an array of shape (N*M*1000) to an array of one dimension